# Installed 12.10 on my lenovo netbook s10-3 and cannot use wireless connections

Tags: 12.10, wireless, lenovo

I installed 12.10 on my Lenovo netbook and I cannot turn on the wireless network switch in the settings. The wireless card in my netbook is active (light is on) I ran sudo lshs and came up with this..

AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
Can someone help me enable it and connect to wifi?

It also says it is softblocked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sudo rfkill unblock all`? If it is being softblocked, that will unblock both hardware and software blocks (unless there is another problem in which case that will not work). Also, are additional drivers installed on the system?

Comment: There are no additional drivers on my computer. When I enter sudo rfkill unblock all it just says

Comment: I found this: http://linuxplained.com/how-to-fix-atheros-ar9285-ar9287-wireless-problems-in-ubuntu-1104/

It appears there are quite a few people with a similar problem with the same wireless card.